# Using RoleClaims as permission checks with Identity .NET EFCore 2.0

Tags: asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity, asp.net-core-2.0

My application will have users who can apply to be part of organisations. As member of an organisation you can get permission to manage parts of the organisation, for example edit-membership-status. This permission will only apply to this organisation. The application will no be multi-tenant, the user will have one login but can be a member of several organisations.

I'm using .Net core 2.0 with Entity Framework and Identity. I have managed to setup users, roles, claims and roleclaims. I have added an organisationId to the IdentityRole and extended IsInRole to check that the role belongs to the correct organisation.

```
public static bool IsInRole(this ClaimsPrincipal user, Role role, Guid 
organisationId)
    {
        var isInRole = user.IsInRole(role.Name);
        var isCorrectOrganisation = (organisationId == role.OrganisationId);
        return isInRole && isCorrectOrganisation;
    }
```

This allows me to check if a user is in a role and an organisation. I do, however, wish to use a more fine grained approach with permissions. I can add claims to the roles, i.e. CanEdit - MembershipStatus. This claim gets added to the ClaimsPrincipal, but doesn't hold information about the organisationId associated with the role holding the claim.

How can I use role claims to check for permissions restricted to the chosen organisation?
I'm using authorizationhandlers and requirements with the authorization service to check for permissions. In this case checking if User is allowed to Read from the provided membership.

```
var isAuthorizedRead = await _authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(
                User, membership,
                CRUDOperations.Read);
```